# Python 3 pyQt4 updating GUI with variables from multiple modules/classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyqt4

I've written a large program with nested classes/threads and multiple modules. 
I would now like to add a simple GUI and some Labels to display some variables. 
However, the variables are scattered throughout the modules and classes. 
I'm looking for a way to update these variables into the GUI without altering 
the current code too much.

I have a rudimentary understanding of Pyqt4 (i will accept tkinter answers also).

I've tried not to use signals/emits because to my knowledge emits 
must be sent from a Qthread which would mean a complete overhaul of my code, changing 
classes and threads over to Qthreads. Id like to avoid needing to do this if possible. 
Here is one example I've attempted.

***test.py***

```
class Update(Thread): 
    def __init__(self): 
        Thread.__init__(self) 
    def run(self): 

        for i in range(10): 
            time.sleep(2) 
            import test 
            wa.label.setText(str(i)) 

class MyWindow(QWidget):  
    def __init__(self, *args):  
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args) 

        self.label = QLabel(" ") 
        layout = QVBoxLayout() 
        layout.addWidget(self.label) 
        self.setLayout(layout) 

        Update1 = Update() 
        Update1.start() 
        Update1.refresh1 = 'ba' 

        self.label.setText(Update1.refresh1) 


if __name__ == "__main__":  
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    wa = MyWindow()  
    wa.show()  
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code works, but my variables need to update from other modules/classes or threads. The moment I move 'class Update' into a new module like THIS:

***test.py***

```
import test2 


class MyWindow(QWidget):  
    def __init__(self, *args):  
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args) 

        self.label = QLabel(" ") 
        layout = QVBoxLayout() 
        layout.addWidget(self.label) 
        self.setLayout(layout) 

        Update1 = test2.Update() 
        Update1.start() 
        Update1.refresh1 = 'ba' 

        self.label.setText(Update1.refresh1) 


if __name__ == "__main__":  
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    wa = MyWindow()  
    wa.show()  
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***test2.py*** #updates GUI

```
class Update(Thread): 
    def __init__(self): 
        Thread.__init__(self) 
    def run(self): 

        for i in range(10): 
            time.sleep(2) 
            import test 
            test.wa.label.setText(str(i))
```

I get: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wa'`

Also, I was also considering putting class Update() into a Qthread, running it from any module/class where a variable has been updated and using the emit function inside Update(). this would solve having to change my current classes/threads to be Qthreads.

If anyone knows of a simple way I could update my GUI simply by calling a class like update() an example would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `wa` is only set when `__name__ == "__main__"` and that only happens when `test.py` is the main file.

When you do `import test`, you are running another instance of the `test.py` file which is not the main script so it has `__name__ == 'test'` not `__main__`. So, even if `wa` was set, you would be changing another instance of it.

**Possible solution:**

You can get a reference to the `__main__` module and set on the `test2.py` module:

On **test.py**:

```
import test2
test2.parent = sys.modules[__name__]
```

Now, on **test2.py** (do not import `test` but make sure `test` imports `test2`):

```
parent.wa.label.setText('Blablabla')
```