# How can I update an instance variable from within a called module

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, instance-variables

I think my answer is related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965575/python-3-pyqt4-updating-gui-with-variables-from-multiple-modules-classes) but can't quite get my head around it.

I am now realising that my code isn't structured very well, however the current setup is:

**main_run.py**

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.processEvents()
ui1 = new_main_ui.Ui_Form_Main()
ui1.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**new_main_ui**

```
class Ui_Form_Main(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        ...etc...
```

within this class are Qlabel objects which have their text updated as buttons are pressed on the UI.

within **new_main_ui** there is a call to another module (**sqr_pull.py**) which does some stuff. Halfway through **sqr_pull.py** I want to update a Qlabel in my UI, but I can't figure out how to reference the UI instance (ui1) without getting:

```
NameError: name 'ui1' is not defined
```

I've tried trying to pass variables through as I go using `sys.modules[__name__]` as follows:

in **main_run**: `new_main_ui.parent1 = sys.modules[__name__]`

in **new_main_ui**: `sqr_pull.parent2 = sys.modules[__name__]`

and then in **sqr_pull** trying to change using `parent2.QLabel.setText("blahblahblah")

but it again doesn't recognise the instance name. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: If you're mucking around with `sys.modules`, you're definitely doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clean way to give a function access to an object is to pass this object to the function...

```
# worker.py

def work(ui):
    some_result = do_something()
    ui.update(some_result)
    other_result = do_something_else()

# ui.py

import worker

class Ui(object):
    def some_action(self):
        worker.work(self)        

    def update(self, data):
        self.show_data_somewhere(data)
```

Hacking with `sys.modules` or whatever will only result in some unmaintainable mess.

Comment: Ok cool, I have no desire to use `sys.modules` at all. If the sqr_pull module is run with a method within the UI class though, how can I pass the actual instance (ui1) through to the sqr_pull module? I feel like this might be quite a basic concept that as a novice I don't understand yet, so apologies.

Comment: Nevermind, I understand this now. Seems so obvious in hindsight :/ Thanks a lot for your help!